# Django TinyMCE image uploader

Tags: python, django, tinymce-4

I have been stuck for a while regarding using tiny-mce-lite4 with Django. I am unable to set it up so it uploads images directly into the editor while in the admin page. I have tried reading the docs, but as a beginner, I can't understand what they are specifying needs to be done.

At the moment I currently have one app set up called 'main' along with the initial file that came when starting the project.

What I have done so far:

1. Install tiny-mce, grapelli and Django filebrowser
2. Set up a static file and media file within the 'main' directory.
3. my *urls.py* looks like this:

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path, include
   from filebrowser.sites import site
   from django.conf.urls.static import static
   from django.conf import settings

   urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
       path('',include('main.urls')),
       path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
       path('admin/filebrowser/',site.urls),
       path('grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),  
   ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

If someone could give me a quick run down of how image uploads work in tinymce or another text editor, I would really appreciate it. Obviously, I would prefer something that will work easily when transitioning between development and production.

Comment: Are you using [django-tinymce](https://django-tinymce.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#configuration) as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
easy to use and documentation
https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor

Comment: I got it working with ckeditor, thanks for the tip man, that seems much easier to use